# What does exactly fetch does in eclipse git (EGIT)?

Tags: eclipse, git

In git documentation says fetch doesnt merge with your working tree. So lets say I have these branches: master, jhonny and miguel. Let's say master is for the last production code release.

```
--------------------------------------------master
                         \-----------------------miguel
                          \---------------------------jhonny
```

Miguel and I have tracking of all branches in our local repo. Lets say Miguel commit and push his brach to the github repo. I want to have the miguel push localy. If I do fetch, what will happen? Does fetch just updates the remote repo reference?  Origin in this case.

Vote down if you think this is duplicated. But I couldnt find the answer Im looking for yet.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `git fetch` only updates the local copy of the remote repo (i.e. the remote reference) - it doesn't then merge those updates into the local branch the way `git pull` does.

In this sense, `git fetch` is quite 'safe' as there are no merge issues and all of your local branches remain untouched. For a more detailed discussion, see: [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

If after a `git fetch` you do want to merge the remote changes with the local branch, you then need to run a `git merge`. This is in effect what `git pull` does.

Comment: In this case, I dont have to keep local tracking of miguel branch since I can merge local jhonny with remote miguel. Is this correct?

Comment: If both you and miguel are tracking the same branch on the remote (e.g. github) repo, then, no, you don't need to keep a local 'miguel' branch. All you would do is (once miguel has pushed to the remote), run a fetch, which will update your remote reference, and then at your leisure merge that with your local branch