# How to disable merge option in Eclipse Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control, merge

I want to disable the option **merging** in my Eclipse Git, to stop merging my code unknowingly?

Because my system is very slow, sometimes I am trying to trigger for synchronize but unfortunately  merge tool has been triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply **[fetch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories)** instead of pulling: that will synchronize the [remote tracking branches](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Tracking_Branches) of your repo, but won't merge anything.

See also "[What does exactly fetch does in eclipse git (EGIT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704201/6309)".